# Encrypt spark dataframe columns with pgcrypto

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pgcrypto

I have a Spark Dataframe and I want to write its data to a PostgreSQL database.
Before or while inserting my data, I want to encrypt some columns with **pgcrypto**.

Is is possible to do it with spark ? If yes how ?